# VBA Unique Sum Code

Tags: vba, loops, sum

I have Surnames in Column A, First Names in Column B, Dates in Column C and Hours worked in Column D.

E.G.

```
Surname First Name Date      Hours  
COX     Daniel     3/03/2015 6  
COX     Daniel     3/03/2015 4      
COX     Daniel     4/03/2015 3.5
COX     Daniel     4/03/2015 4  
COX     Daniel     4/03/2015 2.5    
COX     Daniel     4/03/2015 0
```

I would like to sum the number of hours each person has worked each day into a new sheet.

```
Surname First Name Date      Hours
COX     Daniel     3/03/2015 10
COX     Daniel     4/03/2015 10
```

I have a code that works, however, it is very longwinded and would like to see how I can improve my coding. My code is also limited by the number of entries on a specific date (I have done up to 6 entries); there could be more.

```
Sub WorkHours()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim R As Integer
For R = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

'Sort Data by Date and then by Surname
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:N").Sort key1:=Range("C2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:N").Sort key1:=Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

'Sum Work Hours for One Day
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
If Range("C" & R) = Range("C" & (R + 1)) And Range("C" & R + 1) = Range("C" & (R + 2)) And Range("C" & R + 2) = Range("C" & (R + 3)) And Range("C" & R + 3) = Range("C" & (R + 4)) And Range("C" & R + 4) = Range("C" & (R + 5)) And Range("C" & R + 5) <> Range("C" & (R + 6)) Then
Range("C" & R).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(5, 2) = Application.Sum(Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(5, 1)))
End If
If Range("C" & R) = Range("C" & (R + 1)) And Range("C" & R + 1) = Range("C" & (R + 2)) And Range("C" & R + 2) = Range("C" & (R + 3)) And Range("C" & R + 3) = Range("C" & (R + 4)) And Range("C" & R + 4) <> Range("C" & (R + 5)) Then
Range("C" & R).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(4, 2) = Application.Sum(Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(4, 1)))
End If
If Range("C" & R) = Range("C" & (R + 1)) And Range("C" & R + 1) = Range("C" & (R + 2)) And Range("C" & R + 2) = Range("C" & (R + 3)) And Range("C" & R + 3) <> Range("C" & (R + 4)) Then
Range("C" & R).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(3, 2) = Application.Sum(Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(3, 1)))
End If
If Range("C" & R) = Range("C" & (R + 1)) And Range("C" & R + 1) = Range("C" & (R + 2)) And Range("C" & R + 2) <> Range("C" & (R + 3)) Then
Range("C" & R).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 2) = Application.Sum(Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1)))
End If
If Range("C" & R) = Range("C" & (R + 1)) And Range("C" & R + 1) <> Range("C" & (R + 2)) Then
Range("C" & R).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2) = Application.Sum(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1))
End If
If Range("C" & R) <> Range("C" & (R + 1)) Then
Range("C" & R).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
End If
Next R

'Copy Sheet
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1)
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(2)
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(3).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(3)
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(5).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(4)

'Delete Empty Hours Columns
Sheets("Sheet2").Select`

On Error Resume Next
Columns("D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`

'AutoFit Columns
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should name your range of cells. You should then save your workbook, and click

Data>From Other Sources>From Microsoft Query

You should then select Excel Files, Ok, then navigate to your Excel file. You should select your range, then click Ok. Then, drop in the following SQL statement, updated for your range

```
SELECT Values.Surname, Values.[First Name], Values.Date, SUM(Values.Hours) _
 FROM Values Value GROUP BY Values.Surname, Values.[First Name], Values.Date
```

Comment: Thanks, noted! I am more interested in a better way to code this however. Instead of using multiple IF statements, having a SUMIF kind of loop which checks the dates and surnames and then sums accordingly..

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by checks the dates and surnames. Could you clarify the ordering or grouping of dates or surnames? These can be done easier through SQL than VBA code, at least for this example.

Comment: Surname First Name Date Hours
COX D 03/03/15 6
COX D 03/03/15 4
COX D 04/03/15 3.5
COX D 04/03/15 4
COX D 04/03/15 2.5
COX D 04/03/15 0
DALLY E 02/03/15 3.5
DALLY E 02/03/15 3
DALLY E 02/03/15 3.5
DALLY E 03/03/15 6
DALLY E 03/03/15 4
DALLY E 04/03/15 3.5
DALLY E 04/03/15 4
DALLY E 04/03/15 2.5
DALLY E 04/03/15 0
DALLY E 05/03/15 5
DALLY E 05/03/15 5
DALLY E 06/03/15 3.5
DOBBIE J 02/03/15 3.5
DOBBIE J 02/03/15 3
DOBBIE J 02/03/15 3.5
DOBBIE J 03/03/15 6
DOBBIE J 03/03/15 4
DOBBIE J 04/03/15 3.5
DOBBIE J 04/03/15 4
DOBBIE J 04/03/15 2.5
DOBBIE J 04/03/15 0
DOBBIE J 05/03/15 5

Comment: Basically there are a number of employees for which I need to count hours for in a particular day.. It's just sorted by date and then by name. Not familiar with SQL but thanks mate.